# colors for single series in highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am trying to achieve something like shown in the picture.

- my code is below, in that for "90", and "130", and "110" i want to give separate colors,is there any way (fixed)

[The Visual of the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFCvC.png)

```
series: [{
    name: 'Historic <br/> $850,000' ,
    title: 'Historic',
    data: [90, 130,110],
    pointWidth: 60,
    color: '#0066FF'
}]
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: yep, by giving each point a colour instead of the series.

Comment: yup, got the solution!! thx for reply rahul!

Comment: Good job making each question a specific topic instead of having multiple problems in one question! Hope you enjoy StackOverflow!

Comment: but, i got -1 for that other question, dont know y :( ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize each point as an object instead of just a value, and then supply a `color` attribute. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ondkloss/xycLj24r/)):

```
series: [{
    data: [{ y: 7.0, color: 'orange' }, { y: 6.9, color: 'green' }, { y: 9.5, color: 'blue' }]
}]
```

Or you can set the series to `colorByPoint` and use the `colors` array, for example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ondkloss/xycLj24r/1/)):

```
colors: ['orange', 'green', 'blue'],
series: [{
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5]
}]
```

Comment: coooool!!  its very easy!  thanks for this solution :)